# inserting large number of dates

Tags: php, sql, mysql

How can I insert all dates in an year(or more) in a table using sql

My `dates` table has following structure

`dates(date1 date);`

Suppose I want to insert dates between `"2009-01-01"` to `"2010-12-31"` inclusive.

Is there any sql query for the above?

Comment: Can you use any scripting language? It might make things easier.

Comment: maybe you should use a cursor ?
select your first date in first loop,and then dateadd(1,d,date) each interaction while inserting...

http://ekdd.co.il/loop-though-each-query-results/

Comment: @EudeneK: Don't you think that would be tedious as compared to a simple php script?

Comment: you asked for sql query for above. Cursor is easy to write and should be a problem if you intend to use it once a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do a simple loop:

```
$start = mktime(12,0,0,1,1,2009);
$end = mktime(15,0,0,12,31,2009);

$values = array();
for($time = $start; $time <= $end; $time += 86400) {
    $values[] = date('Y-m-d', $time);
}

$query = "INSERT INTO dates(`date`) VALUES ('".implode("'), ('", $values)."')";

mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 7):

A pure mysql solution using a stored procedure and REPEAT UNTIL:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_many_dates(number_to_insert INT)
BEGIN
  SET @x = 0;
  SET @date = '2010-01-01';
  REPEAT 
      SET @x = @x+1;
      INSERT INTO your_table(your_column) VALUES(@date);
      SET @date = DATE_ADD(@date, INTERVAL 1 day);
  UNTIL @x > number_to_insert END REPEAT;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

Call it by

```
CALL insert_many_dates(1000);
```

Comment: Probably more useful written with two parameters for start date and stop date. OR have it pick up the last date in the dates table and proceed from there, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Dates on a table]

**Dates on a table!**

Seriously though, I don't know a pure mySQL way to do this (but would be interested to see whether there is one.)

In PHP:

```
$start_timestamp = strtotime("2009-01-01 00:00:00");
$end_timestamp =   strtotime("2009-12-31 23:59:59");

// $interval can be anything strtotime() can handle, 2 days, 1 week, 6 hours... 
$interval =        "1 day";  

$timestamp = $start_timestamp;

while ($timestamp < $end_timestamp)
 {
   $query = "INSERT INTO tablename (date_column)".
            " VALUES (".date("Y-m-d", $timestamp).");";
   echo $query."<br>";
   // execute query here....
   $timestamp = strtotime("+ ".$interval, $timestamp);
  }
```

Comment: where is `$end` variable coming from in while loop?

Comment: Cheers @Sarfraz, forgot to add `_timestamp` there. Corrected.

Comment: And noone think of the relational model which says to store only the actual data, not empty sheets.

Comment: @Col true and good point, but the OP is giving too little information to tell what is being planned here. It may be the right way to do whatever the OP has to do. But then, it also might not.

Answer (score 0):

I know of a simple query that works for Oracle, but I have no idea if it will work on mySQL

```
insert into DATES_TABLE (
       select sysdate+level-1 as a_date 
       from dual 
       connect by level <= 365)
```

Just replace `sysdate` with an argument that contains the date you want to start from and replace `365` with the number of days you want to look forward.

Hope this helps. I didn't test its performance thoroughly but it should be very quick.

Answer (score 0):

The pure MYSQL way of doing this is:

```
select * from (
select  date('2009-01-01') + interval (@count := @count +  1 )-1 day d
from (select @count := 0) count
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as two
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as four
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as eight
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as sixteen
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as thirty_two
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as sixty_four
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as one_two_eight
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as two_five_six
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as five_twelve
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as one_thousand_twenty_four) d
where d between '2009-01-01' and '2010-12-31';
```

and its super fast as well!